# How can I import category_ids from excel file to categories_products join table in rails ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, import-from-excel

I have excel file inside a column name category_ids . I need to import to join table, `categories_products` , from excel file in Rails. 
How can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  desc 'import data for models'
  task datas: [:environment] do

   categories_sheet = sheet.sheet('category')
   (2..categories_sheet.last_row).each do |j|
    category_row = categories_sheet.row(j)
    category = Category.create!(id: category_row[0], name: 
    category_row[1])
    print category.id
    categories_sheet = sheet.sheet('category')
   end

   product_sheet = sheet.sheet('product')
   (2..product_sheet.last_row).each do |j|
    product_row = product_sheet.row(j)
    product = Product.create!(id: product_row[0], 
    name: product_row[1])
    category_ids = product_row[2].split(",")
    product.category_ids = category_ids
    product_sheet = sheet.sheet('product')
end
end
```